# Getting File not found error doing point in time database restore in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

So I'm testing out some of our DR stuff and tried to restore a point in time backup from one of our main databases to a new database on the same server.

I am admin on the box and I'm RDP'd into the box and am using SSMS to do the restore.

When I choose my database the "select the backup sets to restore" window populates with a ton of our 1hr incremental backups all the way back to about 30 days ago.

When I select a random time out of the set I get the error "Cannot Open Backup Device {guid}. Operating System error 2, the system cannot find the file specified."

I'm restoring to a new .mdf and .ldf on a different local drive but I have access to everything.

Not sure what's going on or where to diagnose which file it can't find.

Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. How to restore a backup and/or debug the backup process is offtopic.

Comment: @MarcB You are correct Marc. I apologize profusely! It's force of habit that I come here to post/read and didn't even think about the content of my question and the purpose of this site. I'm a developer stuck with a DBA task :\

Comment: This was off-topic for SO and cross-posted to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51671/getting-file-not-found-error-doing-point-in-time-database-restore-in-sql-server so I think it can safely be closed/deleted here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is already answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51671/getting-file-not-found-error-doing-point-in-time-database-restore-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

1st you need to do a `restore` from the `last full-backup` and then you can restore the differential back-ups to restore into a point in time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm going to post this on another site that's related but I did a full backup, restored it as another DB then tried to restore.